# How to read the #hash (or fragment identifier) of the current page URL?

Tags: javascript, url, fragment-identifier

If I am on `https://www.website.com/#something`, how can I return the hash value `"something"` from the URL?

Comment: `window.location.hash` its gives u the hash

Comment: @Sandeep: that's clearly the answer, why not simply post it *as* an answer?

Comment: @DavidThomas, agreed!

Comment: posted jus now :) @Christian u can accept it as answer

Comment: PASS VALUE TO PHP??? make an ajax call and send the hash to PHP.

Comment: @Sandeep Why so many question marks? I'm pretty sure my question came across understandable.

Comment: Nothing simple like `$PHP_Varaibel = document.write(location.hash);`

Comment: Looking at @Sandeep's uppercased question, you may have edited/deleted comments since last I looked, so may I ask: what is it you're trying to do with the hash? Show/hide something, submit it to a server (Ajax, etc), concatenate with another variable or something else entirely?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`window.location.hash` 
its that simple.

donot use all those methods which consume CPU and effects performance.

If DOM provides something predefined use it first.

To pass value to PHP please do and ajax call to php.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl.php',
    data: {hash: hash},
    success: function(){}
})
```

Comment: I knew how to do an ajax call, but that's the only way?

Comment: ya thats the only way to access a server-side language from browser AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) property to grab the hash of the current page:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

### update

As there is a built in method to get the hash via DOM above answer is not appropriate

```
   var hashTag = window.location.hash
   alert(hashTag);
```

will do the magic.

### Old answer

You can do something as below if you have multiple hashes in your url

```
//var href = location.href; // get the url in real worl scenario
var href = "www.bla.com#myhashtag"; // example url
var split = href.split("#"); // split the string; usually there'll be only one # in an url so there'll be only two parts after the splitting
var afterSplit = "Error parsing url";
if(split[1] != null){
    afterSplit = split[1];
}
// If everything went well shows split[1], if not then de default error message is shown
alert(afterSplit);
```

Here is an example <kbd>**[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/JR8yU/)**</kbd>

Comment: DOM already provides u a predefined variable location.hash then its waste of using this method

Comment: I didn't down vote, but that's way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @DavidThomas I agree with you. Updated the answer.

Comment: Weird voting on this question.  The correct answer gets two downvotes, while the convoluted answer, later changed to copy the correct answer gets two upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this

```
h=new URL(location).hash.split`&`.find(e=>/hash_name/.test(e)).split`=`[1]
```

Comment: Why is this bad?