# how I can save a information with javascript without cookies

Tags: javascript

I have a 2 steps form for sign up users.

Now I want when the users one time complete the first steps for next time the first step isn't show .

TNQ

Comment: Check out localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookie

Comment: FWIW: There is a nice JS plugin called [Basil.js](https://github.com/Wisembly/basil.js/tree/master) that allows you to store persistant data. It will take care of storing it in cookies, sessionStorage or localStorage based on the user's browser capabilities. And it's easy to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a hidden input field ([tutorial on input fields](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp)) or a hidden label or data attributes ([tutorial on data attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)).

Sample code:

```
var id = 1; // the ID I want to keep among steps
$("#myHiddenField").val(id);
...
// at step 2, for example
var idStep1 = $("#myHiddenField").val();
```

These value will be stored in the HTML so if the page is refreshed you'll lose the data. If you want to keep it even after a refresh and you don't want to use cookies, you can save the values in the URL (you can read more about this in [tutorial on url hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741421/read-hash-from-url-with-jquery)).

Example of hash on URL:

1. Step 1: www.mysite.com
2. Click next on step 1.
3. a) Step 1 is not visible anymore.

   b) Step 2 is visible.

   c) URL is updated, appending extra information like an ID (www.mysite.com#step2?id=1)

Comment: @unbl0ck3r Just in case you don't know this, this method will store the data in the HTML, but if the page is reloaded / changed, that info will be lost (it's equivalent -and less convenient- to using a simple variable). If you want persistant information, use localStorage.

Comment: localStorage depends on HMLT5 and you don't know the target users. You can combine HTML hidden input fields or data attributes with URL parameters.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein can you give me a sample code?

Comment: This answer is just wrong, you're not actually storing anything. You're just manipulating DOM within the current document. The correct answer is [The Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: You are storing the values in the URL and the DOM. Using AJAX you can save data in the DB after step 1 is completed but he's only asking about client side persistance. A solution is good depending on constraints and you don't know all the constraints nor do I. This is valid solution that could be applied in this scenario, I'm not saying it's the perfect solution for all the cases.